# identifier starts immediately after numeric literal in javascript array

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to assign a php array of image filenames to a javascript array. Here's what I got so far:

```
<script src="jq.js"></script>

<?php
$dir  = 'images';
$images = scandir($dir);
$true_images = array();
foreach($images as $k=>$v){
    if(is_file('images/'.$v)){
        $true_images[] = $v;
    }
}

?>
<script>
$(function(){
        var image_array = Array(<?php echo implode(',', $true_images); ?>);
        alert(image_array);
});
</script>
```

But I get the following error in firebug:
identifier starts immediately after numeric literal

Please help, thanks in advance

Comment: Because your problem is a JavaScript problem, post the output of your PHP script instead. I have a feeling you might see what your problem is by just taking a look at the output (which you should have done before posting)

Comment: Also, the proper way to output JavaScript data is `<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($data)); ?>`, which will prevent a lot of problems and security hazards.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen: here's the output: 1.jpg,2.jpg,5.jpg,6.jpg,7.jpg,8.jpg,9.jpg.

Comment: @Kyouka Suigetsu: And you didn't see anything wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must input your string array into "" or ''
try this

```
var image_array = ["<?php echo implode('","', $true_images); ?>"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do a View Source in your browser and read through the JavaScript you're actually sending, the problem will probably be obvious. "identifier starts immediately after numeric literal" suggests that you have something like `3m` or `3.m` (where `3` or `3.` is a numeric literal and `m` is an identifier). The most likely issue, in my opinion, is that (some of) the values in `$true_images` are things like `3.jpg`. Before sending them to the browser, you need to wrap the filenames in quotation marks, producing things like `"3.jpg"`.